# How much does the Iron Man Mk 1 suit weigh?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

I’m talking about the Iron Man Mk 1 suit from the first movie, the one he uses to escape the cave.

[image: The Mk 1 suit in the cave entrance]

Comment: Q. What does Iron Man weigh? A. His options, very carefully.

Comment: What I meant by that is how many of any units, (grams, pounds, etc.) the Mk 1 suit ways in the movies.

Comment: The confusion likely comes from your use of the word "way" rather than "weigh".

Answer (score 14):

The original Iron Man Mk1 suit is described as being approximately 1500 pounds (over half a metric ton) when fully loaded with ordnance and fuel.

> **ARMOR DESCRIPTION: MARK I:**
>
> ORIGINAL EXOSKELETON CONCEPT, WITH BULLET PROOF IRON-COPPER-MAGNESIUM
> ALLOY. **WHEN FULLY LOADED, IT WEIGHS 1,500 POUNDS**, WITH LIQUID
> PROPELLANT TANKS THAT OFFER BASIC FLYING FUNCTIONS. THE PRIMARY
> WEAPONS CONSIST OF A FLAMETHROWER AND MICRO-MISSILES.
>
> <sub><sup>[Marvel's Iron Man 3 - JARVIS: A Second Screen Experience](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel%27s_Iron_Man_3_-_JARVIS:_A_Second_Screen_Experience)</sup></sub>

[image]